# How to check equal of value arrays in JSON by PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to check two arrays. If the value of one array anybody equal then $response:1 and otherwise for $response:0
example arrays:

```
{"data_comment":[{"name":"a"},{"address":"b"},{"age":"16"}]}

{"data_comment2":[{"name":"b"},{"address":"e"},{"age":"18"}]}
```

file php :

```
if($data_comment==$data_comment2){
    $response2["success"] = "1";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response2);
} else {
    $response2["success"] = "0";
    $response2["message"] = "Error";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response2)
     }
```

so , if any value of data_comment is same with data_comment2 value, then result will be false [$response2["success"] = "0"; ]..

but with my code, result always show [$response2["success"] = "1"; ] , there's is not same value at all between data_comment and data_comment2 .

thanks for any advice

Comment: What does "similar" mean?

Comment: Can we see the code that gets `$data_comment`?  Do you do `json_decode()`?  This may be failing on invalid JSON, which would cause both variables to be `false` and equal each other.

Comment: This does not really seem like a complete question to me.

Comment: Best solution for you would be to decode each of the json strings, and in a foreach loop check similarity as you need to. You can always re-encode them later.